# Parsing Transact SQL with RegEx

Tags: regex, t-sql, parsing, text

I'm quite inexperienced with RegEx - just an occasional straighforward RegEx for a programming task that I worked out by trial and error, but now I have a serious regEx challenge:

I have about 970 text files containing Sybase Transact SQL snippets, and I need to find every table name in those files and preface the table name with ' #'. So my options are to either spend a week editing the files by hand or write a script or application using regEx (Python 3 or Delphi-PRCE) that will perform this task.

**The rules are as follows:**

***Table names are ALWAYS upperCase -  so I'm only looking for upperCase
words;***

***Column names,  SQL expressions and variables are ALWAYS lowerCase;***

***SQL keywords, Table aliases and  column values CAN BE upperCase,  but must NOT be prefixed with ' #';***

***Table aliases (must not be prefixed) will always have whiteSpace preceding them until the end of the
previous word, which will be a table name.***

***Column values (must not be prefixed) will either be numerical values or characters enclosed in
quotes.***

Here is some sample  text requiring application of all the above mentioned rules:

```
update SYBASE_TABLE
set ok = convert(char(10),MB.limit)
from MOVE_BOOKS MB, PEOPLEPLACES PPL
where MB.move_num = PPL.move_num
AND PPL.mot_ind = 'B'
AND PPL.trade_type_ind = 'P'
```

So far with I've gotten only this far: (not too far...)

(?-i)[[:upper:]]

Any help would be most appreciated.
TIA,

MN

Comment: That sounds very bad.  SQL is so complex.  There is the obvious update table, from table, etc.  But adding joins will be painful, the other three or four ways of putting table names in SQL, and the 50 billion other SQL command even more so.  Do you have a way to find every sql command uniquely?  You might want to try and categorize the commands by frequency and complexity.  Use automated scripts on the frequent examples and manual on the less frequent ones.

Comment: Do you have a list of all the possible table names? Perhaps retrievable from the `information_schema` views? You could just search for those specifically instead. `TABLE1|TABLE2|TABLE3`

Comment: @Seth - 'bad...' agreed... your idea is interesting, but it might take me longer than doing it by hand.

Comment: @Martin - this might be a very good idea will investigate. Tnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not doable with a simple regex-replacement. You will not be able to make a distinction between upper case words that are tables, are string literals or are commented:

```
update TABLE set x='NOT_A_TABLE' where y='NOT TABLES EITHER' 
-- AND NO TABLES HERE AS WELL
```

### EDIT

You seem to think that determining if a word is inside a string literal or not *is* easy, then consider SQL like this:

```
-- a quote: '
update TABLE set x=42 where y=666
-- another quote: '
```

or

```
update TABLE set x='not '' A '''' table' where y=666
```

### EDIT II

Okay, I (obsessively) hammered on the fact that a simple regex replacements is not doable. But I didn't offer a (possible) solution yet. What you *could* do is create some sort of "hybrid-lexer" based on a couple of different regex-es. What you do is scan through the input file and at the start of each character, try to match either a `comment`, a `string literal`, a `keyword`, or a `capitalized word`. And if none of these 4 previous patterns matched, then just consume a single character and repeat the process.

A little demo in Python:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re 

input = """
UPDATE SYBASE_TABLE
SET ok = convert(char(10),MB.limit) -- ignore me!
from MOVE_BOOKS MB, PEOPLEPLACES PPL
where MB.move_num = PPL.move_num
-- comment '
AND PPL.mot_ind = 'B '' X'
-- another comment '
AND PPL.trade_type_ind = 'P -- not a comment'
"""

regex = r"""(?xs)          # x = enable inline comments, s = enable DOT-ALL
  (--[^\r\n]*)             # [1] comments
  |                        # OR
  ('(?:''|[^\r\n'])*')     # [2] string literal
  |                        # OR
  (\b(?:AND|UPDATE|SET)\b) # [3] keywords
  |                        # OR
  ([A-Z][A-Z_]*)           # [4] capitalized word
  |                        # OR
  .                        # [5] fall through: matches any char
"""

output = ''

for m in re.finditer(regex, input): 
    # append a `#` if group(4) matched
    if m.group(4): output += '#'
    # append the matched text (any of the groups!)
    output +=  m.group()

# print the adjusted SQL
print output
```

which produces:

```
UPDATE #SYBASE_TABLE
SET ok = convert(char(10),#MB.limit) -- ignore me!
from #MOVE_BOOKS #MB, #PEOPLEPLACES #PPL
where #MB.move_num = #PPL.move_num
-- comment '
AND #PPL.mot_ind = 'B '' X'
-- another comment '
AND #PPL.trade_type_ind = 'P -- not a comment'
```

This may not be the exact output you want, but I'm hoping the script is simple enought for you to adjust to your needs.

Good luck.

Comment: @Bart - obviously this is no simple regex replacement, but I believe that finding or excluding words in quotes is not among the diffficulties here. Literals must be quoted, table names not.

Comment: @Mikey, you yourself already said _"I'm quite inexperienced with RegEx..."_, and I consider myself quite familiar with regex. So if you believe there _is_ a regex-based solution, by all means, feel free to wait right here in the hope that someone posts such a solution. I wouldn't hold my breath, if I were you. :)

Comment: If you were a bit more experienced with regex, you wouldn't have made the remark _"I believe that finding or excluding words in quotes is not among the diffficulties here"_. This ***is*** the difficulty here.

Comment: @Bart - I believe there probably is a RegEx solution - not based on any particular knowledge I have but because I think that RegEx can do just about anything when it comes to parsing text. But I won't hold my breath - I think Martin's suggestion will enable me to do the job. Be that as it may, if you are quite familiar with RegEx I must defer to you, but since a quotation mark is a discrete, known symbol with clear rules regarding its placement, I don't see the difficulty - if that was the only problem, I wouldn't need RegEx at all.

Comment: @Mikey, _"I think that RegEx can do just about anything when it comes to parsing text"_, you are gravely mistaken. If you don't see the difference with regex and a recursive descent parser, you ought to do some reading about them both (no offense meant!). Sure, some regex flavors have the capability to define recursive pattern, but parsing large chunks of SQL reliable with regex is just madness: you can't do it. The fact that no one here on SO suggested some sort of regex is telling.

Comment: _but since a quotation mark is a discrete, known symbol with clear rules regarding its placement, I don't see the difficulty_, the quotation marks can occur inside comments as well. And replacing all comments first to make that less difficult would bring other problems with it: consider the string literal `'foo -- bar'`: you don't want `-- bar'` to be replaced by such pre-processing.

Comment: @Bart - "you don't want -- bar' to be replaced by such pre-processing.": My limited understanding leads me to believe that 'LookAHeads' in PRCE RegEx can handle this.

Comment: @Mikey, no, by possibly removing comments as a preprocessing step, look ahead won't work. You seem to have your mind set on an outcome and I see that convincing you is pointless. I will remove my answer shortly. Best of luck.

Comment: @Bart - "mind set on an outcome" - no, not so. And to prove it, I accepted your answer!

Comment: @Mikey, :) I almost thought I met someone more stubborn than I am! Jokes aside though, see my **EDIT II**

Comment: @Bart - I see your edit II and I understand your approach. I now agree entirely with what you said about quotes sometimes posing difficulty. But one problem your routine doesn't appear to address, the one bothering me most from the start: SQL Aliases - which should not be prefixed; This is why I thought I would need lookaheads etc. I will fool around with your script, it's interesting and educational - of course I will have to add a few more SQL keywords, but I don't think that's a problem - the SQL is mostly simple and SQL is a succinct language. Thanks Much!

Comment: @Mikey, you're welcome. You could replace `([A-Z][A-Z_]*)` with `([A-Z_]+(?:\s+[A-Z_]+)?)` so that group 4 optionally matches a second word separated by one or more spaces. That way, the second word (your 'alias') will not get prepended with a `#`.

Comment: @Bart - will fire up python and give it a shot, mostly for the educational benefit. But for production, I think Martin's suggestion will probably shortcut the whole operation. Tnx